# Deselect in VS2015 diagnostic tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, diagnostic-tools

I'm encountering an incredibly frustrating issue with Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools.

In the Events tab, where the list of outputs, exceptions, ado.net stuff, etc gets spit out, when you click on an item, you become unable to deselect it. This causes the list to get stuck on the selected item, even if you've decided you're done with the event and want the scroll to continue naturally - with no items selected, and the last entry always being visible.

The only way I can get the selection to go away (temporarily) is by disabling the outputs of the category of the selected type. It doesn't matter however, because as soon as I enable it, the selection comes back and keeps me stuck. Escape key does not work for deselection as it just defocuses the diagnostic tools.

Is there any way I can UN-select my selection in Diagnostic Tools or is this something that I should be reporting as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the only way is to activate historical debugging and return to live debugging. This is unfortunate, as it's not the speediest method with large projects, so it seems like a bug.

Comment: If this is actually the case, that's horrible.

Comment: Fwiw, you can remove the item you selected by changing your filter. However, upon restoring that item in the filter, it still jumps back to it.